# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use these SQL queries to generate test data in PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT into onboarding_tasks (business_name, updated_at)
SELECT
    'Business name ' || id AS business_name,
    (NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at
FROM generate_series(1,25) as g(id);
```

Generate 4 items into database table using parent id:

```
INSERT into onboarding_task_item (created_at, description, task_id)
SELECT
    (NOW() + (random() * (NOW() + '90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS description,
    ot.id,
    j.id AS gen_id
FROM onboarding_tasks ot
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,4) j(id);
```

When I run the second SQL query I get:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
  Position: 486
```

I'm not sure how the table items should be edited in order to use `ot.id, j.id AS gen_id` in order to make this correct.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use three columns in insert statement `INSERT INTO onboarding_task_item (created_at, description, task_id)` but send four columns in the select statement

```sql
SELECT
    ... AS created_at,      -- first column
    ... AS description,     -- second column
    ot.id,                  -- third column
    j.id AS gen_id          -- fourth column
FROM 
    onboarding_tasks ot
CROSS JOIN 
    generate_series(1,4) j(id);
```